# How to access the complete ClipboardManager history on Android?

Tags: android, clipboard

Is there a way to receive not just the primary Clip from Android's ClipboardManager?

I need to access all the clipboard history available.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/51548708/7954210